# Combining to python scripts

Tags: python, python-3.x, gpio

I have following two scripts, or one script and a class.

```
import sys
import time
import pigpio

inactive = False

def cbf(GPIO, level, tick):
   global inactive
   if level == pigpio.TIMEOUT:
      if inactive == False:
         inactive = True
         self.on_goal 
   else:
      if inactive == True:
         inactive = False
         self.on_goal
pi = pigpio.pi()


pin_number = 23

cb = pi.callback(pin_number, pigpio.EITHER_EDGE, cbf)
pi.set_watchdog(pin_number, 30) # get alert if quiet for 30 milliseconds
```

This script reads from an ir sensor and switches "inactive" around once the sensor stops getting a signal and the other way around.

```
class GoalDetector:

    def __init__(self, bus, pin_number, team):
        self.bus = bus
        self.pin = pin_number
        self.team = team

        if self.pin: #Kontrolle Pin vorhanden
            #GPIO.setup(self.pin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
            #GPIO.setup(self.pin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)
            #GPIO.add_event_detect(self.pin, GPIO.FALLING, callback=self.on_goal, bouncetime=10)


        else: #wenn pin nicht vorhanden
            logger.warn("Cannot init GoalDetector {0}, pin not specified".format(self.team))

    def __del__(self):
        if self.pin:
            GPIO.remove_event_detect(self.pin)

    def on_goal(self, channel):
        logger.info("Goal {}!".format(self.team))
        self.bus.notify('goal_event', {'source': 'rpi', 'team': self.team})
```

This class was once supposed to do that, but because of the way my sensor works I have to use the script above.

I don't seem to be able to include the first script in my class without breaking it. I do not get an error message, the program just stops working. If I understand this right, all the first script has to achieve is calling  on_goal.

Comment: Can you give an example of how you tried to combine them? It's a little unclear what you're trying to do.

Comment: If the script works as is, why do you need to combine it with the class?

Comment: Well, the first script only gives me a change in the "inactive" value when something happens on pin 23, or logically speaking, when nothing on pin 23 happens for at least 30 ms. I would now like to call on_goal() in my second script with that. The first script should basically subtitute for gpio.add_event_detect() since this does not work because of the way my sensor works.  Basically I just need some way to call on_goal() once inactive switches values.